# Asking about myself question

Tags: questions

I'd like to ask a person to guess my age.

What is the correct question?

```
Can you guess how old is me?
```

or

```
Can you guess how am I old?
```

or

```
Can you guess how old am I?
```

Comment: Have you seen our [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: No. Is it the better place for beginners?

Comment: I am assuming English is not your first language (correct me if I am wrong). This site is [a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: You are right that English is not my 1st language. Thank you for explanation. I'll ask my questions there

Comment: No problem :) By the way, someone has noted that this question needs you to add some research.

Comment: Too bad that I couldn't remove this question. Do I need to ask a moderator do it instead of me? if my question is off-topic here what is the reason to disable its removing?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question

Answer (score 1):

All your suggestions are wrong. You need to say: "Can you guess how old I am?"